# Changed my site to Single Store mode and now the navigation isn't working correctly

Tags: magento2, multistore, home-page

I recently took over managing an e-commerce site for my client and in looking at the settings I saw that it was set up as a multi-store site. It didn't seem to require that setting so I changed it to Single Store mode. But now the navigation isn't working correctly. The home page shows up blank.

How can I fix this? I tried to add Store views thinking that I could just set it back the way it was but that doesn't seem possible at the moment.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try to flush cache?

Comment: Did you find any exception for this issue in var/log directory?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone! I feel kind of foolish I didn't check the theme. Once I went to Design Configuration>Design>Content I saw that the theme needed to be reselected after the change. This solved all my issues.